# Is it possible to apply groupby in python pandas to an already grouped object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset which looks like below:

```
  File_no    A   B       Date     Batch  State   

0    1       2    3    23-1-2019    2      3
1    2       7    6    23-1-2019    2      4
2    3       9    2    24-1-2019    1      2
3    5       6    3    24-1-2019    2      3
4    6       4    3    24-1-2019    1      4
5    8       2    3    25-1-2019    1      4
```

I want to group the data columns 'A' and 'B' based on date and batch. And then do a shift of rows of these columns based on the sequence of file numbers. For instance, in the above dataframe File no 4 is missing.

I am able to achive the shift function, but I am not able to do it for every group individually.

For e.g: 6 & 8 files are not in sequence, but they are from different dates. So the shift  should not be performed because it is missing a sequence.

```
diff = data['File_no'].diff().ne(1).cumsum() 

grouped=data.groupby(['Date','Batch'])

grouped.apply(lambda data: data.groupby(diff)['A','B'].shift())
```

This performs a shift, whenever there is a missing sequence and doesn't consider the groups into consideration.

Expected output:

```
  File_no    A   B       Date     Batch  State   

0    1       Nan  Nan    23-1-2019    2      3
1    2       2    3      23-1-2019    2      4
2    3       9    2      24-1-2019    1      2
3    5       Nan  Nan    24-1-2019    2      3
4    6       6    3      24-1-2019    1      4
5    8       2    3      25-1-2019    1      4
```

Comment: Is expected output correct? Because if use `for i, df in data.groupby(['Date','Batch']):
    print (df)` get different groups. Is possible use `diff = data['File_no'].diff().ne(1).cumsum() 

df=data.groupby(['Date','Batch',diff])['A','B'].shift()` ? If not, what is reason?

Comment: Hi, yes the expected output is correct. Yes I can use the code you suggested... I guess this should yield me the output. I will verify the output..

Comment: OK, because it is different output like in question, because different groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can pass columns with series to one `groupby`:

```
diff = data['File_no'].diff().ne(1).cumsum() 
data[['A','B']] = data.groupby(['Date','Batch',diff])['A','B'].shift()
print (data)

   File_no    A    B       Date  Batch  State
0        1  NaN  NaN  23-1-2019      2      3
1        2  2.0  3.0  23-1-2019      2      4
2        3  NaN  NaN  24-1-2019      1      2
3        5  NaN  NaN  24-1-2019      2      3
4        6  NaN  NaN  24-1-2019      1      4
4        8  NaN  NaN  25-1-2019      1      4
```

EDIT:

```
r = np.arange(data['File_no'].min(), data['File_no'].max() + 1)
data = data.set_index('File_no').reindex(r)

diff = data.index.to_series().diff().ne(1).cumsum() 
data[['A','B']] = data.groupby(['Date','Batch',diff])['A','B'].shift()
data = data.dropna(how='all').reset_index()
print (data)
   File_no    A    B       Date  Batch  State
0        1  NaN  NaN  23-1-2019    2.0    3.0
1        2  2.0  3.0  23-1-2019    2.0    4.0
2        3  NaN  NaN  24-1-2019    1.0    2.0
3        5  NaN  NaN  24-1-2019    2.0    3.0
4        6  9.0  2.0  24-1-2019    1.0    4.0
5        8  NaN  NaN  25-1-2019    1.0    4.0
```

Comment: yes..just a small change in the output, i got values of File 5 shifted to File 6. So file 6 is not 'NaN'

Comment: @hakuna_code - Nit sure if understand, can you explain more?

Comment: So, if you see File_no 5, it becomes NaN because the sequence abive it is missing(File_no 4 is missing). However File_no 5 will shift its 'A' and 'B' column value to File_no 6 as the sequence is followed. File_no 6 didn't have NaN for A and B when i ran the program

Comment: @hakuna_code - Are values in `File_no` unique and numbers?